# Load data into appropriate fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Say I have a table with the following structure:

```
| Name  | Age |
|-------|-----|
| Peter | 20  |
| Lisa  | 30  |
```

`Name` is of type `String` and `Age` is of type `Int`.

With:

```
SELECT `Name`, `Age` FROM `Tab1`
```

I can load all contents. Then I can parse the request and display it in some text field, so that the user can update them, if needed. That is no problem.

But I also want to differentiate between the data types. So the names should be loaded into a common `<input type="text" />`, whereas age should be loaded into `<input type="number" />`.

Doing so I want to make sure, that the user can only enter numbers into `Age`, also I think it would look "more professional".

Is this a common practice?
How could I load the data types using only one query?

Comment: Your **view** should know how to properly present the data. How it figures out - it's up to you. You can have it hardcoded, mapped, whatever.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: I know how to properly present the data. What I'm looking for is a way to find out the data types. E.g. with a SQL-query.

Comment: You can read table schema but this is usually insufficient. You should have mapping somewhere. Guessing will not work and accepted answer is simply wrong in more serious run. See my coments

Comment: I don't understand the downvoters. What's wrong with my question? I described the problem well and the answer also isn't very trivial to find.

Comment: You are downvoted because your question shows no prior research on subject. You just come here asking "how to do something" instead of looking for solution, especially for common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can match the data types and create the input fields like :

```
<?php
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$data_value)){ //This string contains only digits
   echo "<input type='number' value='{$data_value}' />";
} else{
 echo "<input type='text' value='{$data_value}' />";
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this is wrong approach. What If entered value is just subset of allowed value? By doing this way you presented you won't allow to enter anything more than digits.

Comment: Agreed. It was an idea not a solution. The answer is just to give me an idea on how to bifurcate the digits and strings and assign them in input fields.